# How to (or should I) prevent Go WaitGroup calls Add() during Wait()?

Tags: go, waitgroup

Let's say I have 2 goroutines, one running in another, each needs a waitgroup to prevent goroutine leak. Here is the code:

```
func A(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // do something
}

func B(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    wg.Add(1)  // <- this is for A()
    go A(wg)
    // do something
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)  // <- this is for B()
    go B(wg)
    // do something
    wg.Wait()
}
```

It works well. But it is possible that the `wg.Add(1)` line inside `B()` is called after the `wg.Wait()` in `main()` started. The code is still working well in that case. But this seems to be a potential race condition to me.

Notice that this is not violating [the WaitGroup rule](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add): "calls with a positive delta that occur when the counter is zero must happen before a Wait". Here the `Add()` inside `B()` is happening when the counter is 1.

My question is: is it ok to call `wg.Add()` in one goroutine when `wg.Wait()` is blocking in another goroutine? If not, what's the best practice here? Apparently I can choose to not share one wairgroup for both `A` and `B`, instead to use 2 waitgroups for them respectively, but it will be pretty messy, especially when there are even more functions and we end up with a lot waitgroups to wait.

Comment: Your usecase is 100% supported and that's why the rule you quoted is written as it is :)

Answer (score 4):

It is ok to call `wg.Add` while another goroutine is waiting on `wg.Wait`. There are no race conditions, and it will work fine as long as `wg` does not reach zero before `wg.Add` is called, because that will release `wg.Wait`. In your usage, there is no way `wg` can reach zero, because even if goroutine `B` terminates before `A` starts, `wg` would not reach zero because it is added before the new goroutine starts.